# vectorised comparison of strings to single value in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

The `==` operator in Rcpp works as expected when comparing numeric vectors against a single value.  I.e. each element of the vector is compared to the value and a logical vector is returned.  For example, consider the following which behaves as expected:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
CharacterVector test_vals(NumericVector x) {
  if (is_true(any(x == 3))) return ("Values include 3");
  return ("3 not found");
}')
test_vals(1:2)
# [1] "3 not found"
test_vals(1:5)
# [1] "Values include 3"
```

However, if I try to compare a character vector against a character scalar, it only seems to test the first element of the vector:

```
cppFunction('
CharacterVector test_names(NumericVector x) {
  CharacterVector y = x.attr("names");
  if (is_true(any(y == CharacterVector::create("foo")))) return ("Names include foo");
  return ("foo not found");
}')
test_names(c(a=1, b=2, foo=3))
# [1] "foo not found"
test_names(c(foo=3, a=1, b=2))
# [1] "Names include foo"
```

I know that comparing two character vectors of the same length appears to work in a vectorised manner, as expected:

```
cppFunction('
CharacterVector test_names(NumericVector x) {
  CharacterVector y = x.attr("names");
  CharacterVector foo(x.size());
  foo.fill("foo");
  if (is_true(any(y == foo))) return ("Names include foo");
  return ("foo not found");
}')
test_names(c(a=1, b=2, foo=3))
# [1] "Names include foo"
test_names(c(foo=3, a=1, b=2))
# [1] "Names include foo"
test_names(c(a=1, b=2))
# [1] "foo not found"
```

Does this mean that comparisons of character vectors against a single value has not been implemented in `Rcpp`, or am I just missing how to do it?

Comment: Good question. It does look like `NumericVector` has the appropriate `opeator=()` but `CharacterVector` may not (as characters are generally a different cattle of fish).   We could probably add it; in the meantime you could probably write yourself a little helper that does it 'by hand' for two vectors.

Comment: So to be plain you desire a 'contains()' operator taking a vector of strings, and a single string, returning a boolean?  Phrasing it as `==` is a little "off" to my reading because of many-vs-one mapping here.  You really are looking at a set operator here, right?  (I am with you that in that `std::vector<>` is the single best container...)

Comment: yes - that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: I think we should look at something else then -- think `std::vector<std::string>` and hand it off to the STL which will already do this...

Comment: Glad this helps.  Thinking more about the lack of `==` support:  we generally do not 'recycle' as R does (which some languages call 'broadcast').  So 'many-to-one' comparisons are somewhat uncharted territory.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think what threw me is that the 'recycling' appeared to work with Numeric types, so I expected consistent behavior also for strings.  Although the solution is simple, it took me a while of debugging to uncover that the unexpected behavior was the underlying reason for a bug.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Can I also ask a follow-up question.  If we do the (flawed) comparison of two CharacterVectors `y == x` where y has many and x has one element... will the code try to access elements of x beyond its allocated memory?  I ask because the code I had which used this flawed approach crashed randomly, and a memory leak like this could explain it.

Comment: I invite you to debug it step by step.  Ex ante unclear where it dispatches too.  Also unclear what signature you tried and if / where that may have shown a warning.  As I tried to explain, what you still prefer to have used does (I think) not exists as much as you want to will it into existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on our quick discussion, here is a *very simple* solution as the problem (as posed) is simple -- no regular expression, no fancyness.  Just loop over all elements and return as soon as match is found, else bail with `false`.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool contains(std::vector<std::string> sv, std::string txt) {
    for (auto s: sv) {
        if (s == txt) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*** R
sv <- c("a", "b", "c")
contains(sv, "foo")
sv[2] <- "foo"
contains(sv, "foo")
*/
```

#### Demo

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/66895973/answer.cpp")

> sv <- c("a", "b", "c")

> contains(sv, "foo")
[1] FALSE

> sv[2] <- "foo"

> contains(sv, "foo")
[1] TRUE
>
```

And that is really just shooting from the hip before looking for either what we may already have in the (roughly) 100k lines of Rcpp, or what the STL may have...

The same will work for your earlier example of named attributes as you can the same, of course, with a `CharacterVector`, and/or use the conversion from it to `std::vector<std::string>` we used here, or...  If you have an older compiler, switch the `for` from C++11 style to K+R style.

Comment: I think the `Rcpp` equivalent is to compare an `Rcpp::String` to each element of an `Rcpp::StringVector` (?)

Comment: We _may_ have that. I am not sure.  As I wrote above, faster to whack two lines together than to go digging in the coal mine of documentation...

Comment: At the end of the day it is one of those things that _e.g._ `data.table` already does excellently so I am not too concerned.  People working more with text data as _e.g._ the `quanteda` team may know more.